# drupal Administration views cause a json dump when I Save

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, administration

I'm using administration views to customize every admin section.

My problem appears when I filter.

Example:
I have a section called Manage Videos. I have a dropdown to filter on VideoType. I choose for example (Action movies) and click Apply. Every Action movie will show in a table. Now I click on the EDIT button and a popup is showing up with a form to modify my movies.

When I click SAVE, I get a white page with json dump.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
The problem **does not come** if I don't Filter something.

```
[

    {
        "command": "settings",
        "settings": {
            "basePath": "/",
            "pathPrefix": "",
            "ajaxPageState": {
                "theme": "conchitas",
                "theme_token": "0oS3RgDWhpTzLQ6vlgShkZFnbmkuwbffuXec_a3ipew"
            },
            "overlay": {
                "paths": {
                    "admin": "node/*/webform\nnode/*/webform/*\nnode/*/webform-results\nnode/*/webform-results/*\nnode/*/submission/*\nnode/*/edit\nnode/*/delete\nnode/*/revisions\nnode/*/revisions/*/revert\nnode/*/revisions/*/delete\nnode/add\nnode/add/*\noverlay/dismiss-message\nuser/*/shortcuts\nadmin\nadmin/*\nbatch\ntaxonomy/term/*/edit\nuser/*/cancel\nuser/*/edit\nuser/*/edit/*",
                    "non_admin": "admin/structure/block/demo/*\nadmin/reports/status/php"
                },
                "pathPrefixes": [
                    "en",
                    "fr"
                ],
                "ajaxCallback": "overlay-ajax"
            }
        },
        "merge": true
    }

]
```

I tried many things such as:

- Disabling jquery_update
- Reinstalling administration views and administration menu.

Comment: I Just disable the ajax poast in the views advance option.

Answer (score 0):

Jean-Francois's comment worked for me.  Go into the appropriate view and disable 'Use Ajax' in the 'Advanced' section.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue while using the [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) module, which AJAXifies the  admin view of content and files.

Quick fix for this is to disable the AJAX of the corresponding View.

You probably have the AJAX of the View set to `Yes`. Make sure to set it to `No`.

[image]